# How do I replace values in multiple elements and then use the result in my style sheet

Tags: xml, xslt, replace

I have a working style sheet that I am using to transform the structure and elements to match our entity framework.  However, now I have to change the output of various elements from NA to 0. I don't want to have to put in a test on each element to see if it's NA before I write it out.  There are too many to do that reasonably.  I have tried to use a template match to change the text from NA to 0.  I have played around with samples and was able to use copy and apply-template, but that just outputs a copy of the source data with the converted elements.

```
      <xsl:template match="text()[. = 'NA']">
        <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
      </xsl:template>
```

I need to have something like this work for me:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    version="1.0">
      <xsl:template match="Crash">
        <CrashEntity>
          <xsl:call-template name="crashMain"/>
        </CrashEntity>
      </xsl:template>

      <!--crashMain-->
      <xsl:template name="crashMain">
        <xsl:apply-templates select ="General"/>
      </xsl:template>

      <!--General-->
      <xsl:template match="General">
        <!--WorkZoneType-->
        <DevelopmentType>
          <xsl:value-of select="WorkZoneType"/>  <--WorkZoneType may contain NA-->
        </DevelopmentType>
        <SomeDataType>
          <xsl:value-of select="TrafficControlType"/>  <--TrafficControlType may contain NA-->
        </SomeDataType>
      </xsl:template>

      <!--crashUnits-->
      <xsl:template name="crashUnits">
        <xsl:for-each select="/Crash/Vehicles/Vehicle">
          <xsl:call-template name="crashUnit"/>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:if test ="/Crash/Pedestrians != null">
          <xsl:for-each select="/Crash/Pedestrians">
            <xsl:call-template name="crashPedestrians">
              <xsl:with-param name ="vehicleCount" select ="$vehicleCount"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:template>

      <xsl:template name="crashUnit">
        <CrashUnitsEntity>

          <CargoBodyType>
            <xsl:value-of select ="TruckCover"/>
          </CargoBodyType>
          <VehicleDefects>
            <xsl:value-of select ="VehicleCondition"/>
          </VehicleDefects>
        </CrashUnitsEntity>
      </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is a sample of the source XML:

```
    <Crash>
      <Vehicles>
        <Vehicle VehicleNumber="1">
          <TruckCover>NA</TruckCover>
          <VehicleCondition>1</VehicleCondition>
        </Vehicle>
      <Vehicles>

      <General>
        <WorkZoneType>NA</WorkZoneType>
        <TrafficControlType>6</TrafficControlType>
      </General>
    </Crash>
```

Here is a sample of the expected result:

```
    <CrashEntity>
      <DevelopmentType>0</DevelopmentType>
      <TrafficControlType>5</TrafficControlType>
     <CrashUnits>
        <CrashUnitsEntity>
           <CargoBodyType>0</CargoBodyType>
          <VehicleDefects>1</VehicleDefects>
        </CrashUnitsEntity>
      </CrashUnits>
    </CrashEntity>
```

Comment: There is no `General` element in your XML, so `<xsl:apply-templates select ="General"/>` doesn't do anything and `<xsl:template match="General">` will never be applied. In addition, you have some syntax errors (such as declaring the wrong namespaces at the wrong places). Other than that, your approach would work if instead of `<xsl:value-of select="WorkZoneType"/> ` you would do `<xsl: apply-templates select="WorkZoneType"/>`.

Comment: If the first transformation was made using a `xsl:value` over `xsl:apply-temples`, then you have to revert that or chain the transformation with a second step transformation.

Comment: Another crucial question: what should your output XML look like?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Brilliant solution.  That saved me hours of re-coding which I don't have the time for.  +100 if I could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, thanks to [michael.hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k).
I replaced **value-of** with **apply-templates** where necessary.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="text()[. = 'NA']">
    <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Crash">
    <CrashEntity>
      <xsl:call-template name="crashMain"/>
    </CrashEntity>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--crashMain-->
  <xsl:template name="crashMain">
    <xsl:apply-templates select ="General"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--General-->
  <xsl:template match="General">
    <!--WorkZoneType-->
    <DevelopmentType>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="WorkZoneType"/>  <--WorkZoneType may contain NA-->
    </DevelopmentType>
    <SomeDataType>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="TrafficControlType"/>  <--TrafficControlType may contain NA-->
    </SomeDataType>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--crashUnits-->
  <xsl:template name="crashUnits">
    <xsl:for-each select="/Crash/Vehicles/Vehicle">
      <xsl:call-template name="crashUnit"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:if test ="/Crash/Pedestrians != null">
      <xsl:for-each select="/Crash/Pedestrians">
        <xsl:call-template name="crashPedestrians">
          <xsl:with-param name ="vehicleCount" select ="$vehicleCount"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="crashUnit">
    <CrashUnitsEntity>

      <CargoBodyType>
        <xsl:apply-templates select ="TruckCover"/>
      </CargoBodyType>
      <VehicleDefects>
        <xsl:apply-templates select ="VehicleCondition"/>
      </VehicleDefects>
    </CrashUnitsEntity>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```